# Angular 2 with parsley.js validation can't block the submit button

Tags: angularjs, validation, parsley.js

I have questions about submit button. Now I can use the parsley validation in the form and it works perfectly. However, when user clicks submit button which binds with angular, and if there is an invalid input in the form, my app can't stop executing the click function. All the validations then become useless.

I don't want to use the angular built-in validation since parsely.js can handle so many input situations. The following is my codes:

apply-page.ts

```
import {RouteParams,Router,ROUTER_DIRECTIVES} from '@angular/router-deprecated';

import {Component, ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';
import {Widget} from '../../core/widget/widget';
import {DropzoneDemo} from '../../components/dropzone/dropzone';
import {HolderJs} from '../../components/holderjs/holderjs';
import {NKDatetime} from 'ng2-datetime/ng2-datetime';
import {Autosize} from 'angular2-autosize/angular2-autosize';
import {AlertComponent} from 'ng2-bootstrap/components/alert';

// import models
import {PersonalInfo} from './model/personal-info';
import {Job} from '../model/job';
import {JobService} from '../job-service';
import {NgForm} from '@angular/common';

declare var jQuery: any;

@Component({
  directives: [
    ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, Widget, DropzoneDemo, HolderJs, NKDatetime, Autosize, AlertComponent,
    EducationForm, ExperienceForm
  ],
  selector: '[apply-page]',
  host: {
    class: 'apply-page app'
  },
  template: require('./apply-page.html'),
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  styles: [require('./apply-page.scss'), require('../login-page.scss'), require('./forms-validation.scss')]
})
export class ApplyPage {

  colorOptions: Object = {color: '#f0b518'};
  sliderValueOptions: Array<number> = [200, 1547];

  personalInfo: PersonalInfo;
  extraAddr: string;
  job: Job;

  constructor(
    // the service to get data from mock-data
    private jobService: JobService,
    private routeParams: RouteParams,
    private router:Router
  ){}

  // called only one time at the loading time
  ngOnInit(): void {
    jQuery('#colorpicker').colorpicker(this.colorOptions);
    jQuery('.select2').select2();
    jQuery('.js-slider').slider();
    jQuery('#markdown').markdown();
    jQuery('.selectpicker').selectpicker();

    // initialize parsleyjs to validate the input
    jQuery('.parsleyjs').parsley();

    this.personalInfo = new PersonalInfo();
    this.educations = new Array<Education>();
    this.experiences = new Array<Experience>();
    this.skills = SKILLS;

    // fetch the id from url
    let id = this.routeParams.get('id');
    this.getJob(id);
  }

  // TODO: submit form to server
  onSubmit(){
    console.log("on submit");
  }
```

apply-page.html

```
<form class="parsleyjs" data-parsley-priority-enabled="false" novalidate="novalidate" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
                        <div class="page-section">
                            <div class="page-section-part">
                                <div class="row page-header-row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6 page-sub-title">
                                        PERSONAL INFO
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row page-header-row ">
                                    <div class="col-md-6 medium-text" align="center">Do you have a LinkedIn account?</div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6" align="center">
                                        <input type="image" src="assets/images/pictures/linkedin-button.png" class="img-btn" (click)="getLinkedIn()" onClick="return false" alt="..."/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row page-header-row">
                                    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-3 small-text">We make it easier for you to import your professional profile.</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="widget-body">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="page-label" for="first-name">First name</label>
                                            <input [(ngModel)]="personalInfo.firstName" class="form-control" placeholder="First name" id="first-name" type="text" required ngControl="first-name">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="page-label" for="last-name">Last name</label>
                                            <input [(ngModel)]="personalInfo.lastName" class="form-control" placeholder="Last name" id="last-name" type="text" required ngControl="last-name">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="page-label" for="email">Email</label>
                                            <input [(ngModel)]="personalInfo.email" class="form-control" placeholder="email@domain.com" id="email" type="email" 
                                            data-parsley-trigger="change"
                                            data-parsley-validation-threshold="1"
                                            required data-parsley-required-message=""
                                            ngControl="email">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="page-label" for="phone">Phone</label>
                                            <input [(ngModel)]="personalInfo.phone" class="form-control" placeholder="i.e: Sales, Marketing" id="phone" data-parsley-type="number" required data-parsley-required-message="" ngControl="address">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="page-label" for="address">Address</label>
                                            <input [(ngModel)]="personalInfo.address" class="form-control" placeholder="1200 Fulton st, NY, NY 10001" id="address" type="text" required>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="page-label" for="">Address</label>
                                            <input [(ngModel)]="extraAddr" class="form-control" placeholder="1200 Fulton st" type="text">
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-actions page-section-submit">
                            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-lg mb-xs" role="button">
                                Submit your application
                            </button>
                        </div>
                </form>
```

The button is at the bottom of the apply-page.html file. When clicking the button is will call the onSubmit() function in apply-page.ts. Really want to know if there is any solution about it. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

I've found the way to do that. In ngOnInit(), I should get the instance of parsley by:

```
// initialize parsleyjs to validate the input
this.instance = jQuery('.parsleyjs').parsley();
```

Then, in the onSubmit() function:

```
onSubmit(){
    if(this.instance.isValid()){
      // TODO: submit form to server

    }else {
      console.log("do nothing");
    }
}
```

I should figure out how to use jQuery and parsley in angular 2 first and then try to implement them on my app. Hope this will help others. Thank you.

By the way, here is good video about how to use jQuery in angular 2. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vrdHEBkGAow

Comment: Do you have any advice how to do that? I am new in web application and also this is my first time to use parsley.js in angular 2. Any advice is good to me thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a bug in Parsley, sorry. Specify `type="submit"` in your button and it should work fine.

Comment: I've tried it but it still doesn't work. The angular will still do the onSubmit() function.

Comment: Could you post a working example in an angular playground?

Comment: I've found the answer. I should get the instance of parsleyjs and check if the instance is valid. If the instance is valid, do the submit function. If not, just do nothing. I'll post my code later.

Comment: I've tested with version 2.7.0 and indeed it does not work.