# Angular 2 Parsley Prevent Form Submission When Input is Invalid

Tags: angularjs, angular, parsley.js

```
      <div>
            <form class="form-horizontal form-label-left parsleyjs" method="post" data-parsley-priority-enabled="false"
                (ngSubmit)="submitForm()">
                <fieldset>
                    <div class="form-group row">
                        <label class="form-control-label col-md-3 col-xs-12" for="task-id">
                            ID
                            <span class="help-block"> 
                                Number Only
                            </span>
                        </label>
                        <div class="col-md-9 col-xs-12">
                            <input type="text" id="task-id" name="task-id" class="form-control"
                                data-parsley-type="number"
                                required="required">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
                <div class="form-actions">
                    <button type="submit" id="task-detail-submit-button" class="btn btn-danger btn-rounded pull-xs-right">Submit</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
```

How can the Parsley stop invoking "submitForm()" during form submission when the input is invalid. In this case, "task-id" is not a number.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38446956/angular-2-with-parsley-js-validation-cant-block-the-submit-button

Answer (score 6):

hope this code give you a idea

```
        <form class="form-horizontal form-label-left parsleyjs"   name="formname" method="post" data-parsley-priority-enabled="false"
            (ngSubmit)="formname.valid && formname.submitForm()">
```

This code is not tested if it does not work sorry for it

Comment: This actually does work, I just tested it now. My use case was that a user may opt to change the simple `disabled` HTML directive and submit an invalid form. Adding this bit stops angular from submitting the form in case a user tries to manipulate it and forces it to be valid before it will trigger the function.